# Symfony - use Command to run Phing task

Tags: php, linux, symfony, process, phing

When I try to run that phing command: `bin/phing clear_cache_action` from a console, everything works.  Unfortunately, when I try to run the same command from the controller in the Symfony project I get an error.

That my code:

```
    public function clearAction()
    {
        $process = new Process('bin/phing clear_cache_action');
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }

        echo $process->getOutput();
    }
```

Symfony returns me that error:

```
The command "bin/phing clear_cache_action" failed.

Exit Code: 127(Command not found)

Working directory: /var/www/caolin/web

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
sh: 1: bin/phing: not found
```

Linux commands e.g. 'ls' works properly. 
How can I run phing command from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to execute `phing` from a `Controller`. Thus `Working directory: /var/www/caolin/web` instead of `/var/www/caolin` causes resolving `bin/phing` to `/var/www/caolin/web/bin/phing` which does not exist. You should set your current working directory to `%kernel.project_dir%`:

```php
$process = new Process(
    ['bin/phing', 'clear_cache_action'], 
    $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')
);
$process->run();
```

However, I would not recommend starting a process from a Controller unless you are really sure what you are doing.

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be like: ['bin/phing', 'clear_cache_action'],